# Why didn't Krishna kill Duryodhana?

Tags: mahabharata

If Krishna had killed Duryodhana, a lot of bloodshed could have been avoided, because the Kaurava army would have been demoralized.

Why didn't Krishna kill Duryodhana?

Comment: Only those who has become eligible to get moksha, can only get chance to be killed with hands of God. Krishna only killed those whom he wants to give shelter in his abode. Jai Shree Krishna...

Comment: even more good question is why did he make him alive  after Gandhari destroyed her fetus in the first place, Lord Vedavyasa is aware future happening.

Comment: it should go back to creation question why did he create evil people.. see seed and gardner analogy would help its not gardener responsibility to make mango out of neem tree. whatever he did he planted the seed in the garden of eden it bloomed according to the nature of side and so do the fruits borned by the tree. but it is the responsiblity of gardener to make it grow into full tree and make it  bloom and bear the fruits according to its nature..that is what vyasa and krishna did.. duryodhana seed is bad.. he was given high educatio along with pandavas,

Comment: he was given every opppurtunity. but his nature is todo trouble to others

Answer (score 6):

## Why didn't Krishna kill Duryodhana?

Krishna did not killed Duryodhana because Bhima alrady took the vow to kill Duryodhana in battle in club fight.

After the episode of  disrobing of Draupadi at that same time Karna asked Draupadi to serve Duryodhana , Duryodhana then agreeing with karna and in intention of insulting Bhima uncover his thigh and showed it to Draupadi. Seeing this Bhima became angry and took a vow to kill Duryodhana and to tear away Duryodhanas thigh in battle.

This well know incident is mentioned in [**Mahabharata**](https://archive.org/details/TheMahabharataMNDutt/page/n417)- Sabha Parva - Dyuta Parva- Chapter LXXI -Page 94 - Verse 11-14.

> पितृभि: सह सालोक्यं मा स्म गच्छेत वृकोदर : |
>  यद्येतमूरुं गदया न
>   भिन्द्यां ते महाहवे ||14||
>
> 13 Seeing this Bhimasena expanding his red eyes thus spoke to him
>   (Duryodhana) in the midst of the kings as if placing them (with his
>   words)
>
> 14 Let not Vrikodara go to the regions obtain by his ancestors if he
>   dose not break that thigh in a great battle.

Here Bhima is adressin himself making a a vow to break thigh of Duryodhana. He also clearly made a vow to kill duryodhana as described below.

---

In the second time when after the episode of  disrobing of Draupadi all pandavas were going out of the assembly of kurus .Then at that time Duryodhana insulted Bhima  by mimicking his walking and laughed . Then Bhima warned him that -  Do not think that you will gain any    dominant power or influence over me , I will soon kill you. He took the vow to kill Duryodhana in club fight (Gada Yuddha)  at that time.  Bhimas Vows are are mentioned  In [**Mahabharata**](https://archive.org/details/TheMahabharataMNDutt/page/n423) - Sabha Parva-AnuDyuta Parva - Chapter LXXVII-Verse -24,26,28  below.  Page -101.

> 24 Therupon Vrikodara(Bhima) , half turning towards him said ," O fool
>   do not think that by this you gain any ascendancy over me. I shall
>   soon kill you with all your followersand answer you recalling all this
>   to your mind.
>
> 26 Bhima said
>
> अहं दुर्योधनं हन्ता कर्ण हन्ता धनञ्जय : |
>  शकुनिं चाक्षकितवं सहदेवो
>   हनिष्यति ||26 ||
>
> I shall be  slayer of Duryodhana , Dhananjaya will be slayer of Karna
>   . Shhadeva will kill gambler Shakuni.
>
> सुयोधनमिमं पापं हन्तास्मि गदया युधि |
>  शिर: पादेन
>   चास्याहमशिस्थास्यामि भूतले ||28 ||
>
> 28 I shall kill this sinful wretch Sujo-dhana(Duryodhana)  in a club
>   fight.Felling him on the ground .I shall place my foot on his head.

---

So this is one of the reason Krishna Did not himself killed Duryodhana in order to stop the conflict. We can explain this answer with many more reasons also as Krishna himself took a vow not to took part in battle etc. Above is one of the many reasons that can be explained.

Answer (score 0):

If krishna want then he even stop Duryodhana getting birth but When God birth on earth as Human , they also have to follow all rules of Human body & nature.

They have to let it happen accordingly Karma rules.

God even have to follow karma rules & kill another only when karma ask to do.

Comment: Welcome Aditya To Hinduism SE! When answering the questions on this site it is necessary to add some references in the answer as a support.You can also visit help section of the site to know more about how to write a good answer. –

Answer (score 0):

> If Krishna had killed Duryodhana, a lot of bloodshed could have been avoided, because the Kaurava army would have been demoralized.

What difference would it had made? What bloodshed are you talking about? You didn't understood the point of it all. There's no one who dies or lives.

> य एनं वेत्ति हन्तारं यश्चैनं मन्यते हतम्।
>
> उभौ तौ न विजानीतो नायं हन्ति न हन्यते।।2.19।।
>
> He who takes the Self to be the slayer and he who thinks It is slain, neither of them knows. It slays not, nor is It slain.

It was all part of a play. That what you see as Duryodhana, Arjuna, you and me are Krishna only indeed.

> अहमात्मा गुडाकेश सर्वभूताशयस्थित: |
>
> अहमादिश्च मध्यं च भूतानामन्त एव च || 10.20||
>
> O Arjun, I am seated in the heart of all living entities. I am the beginning, middle, and end of all beings.

You might as well said why did Krishna created this world, a lot of bloodshed would have been avoided in the first place. All these questions arise without knowing what this world is.

> ईश्वरः सर्वभूतानां हृद्देशेऽर्जुन तिष्ठति।
>
> भ्रामयन्सर्वभूतानि यन्त्रारूढानि मायया।।18.61।।
>
> The Lord dwells in the hearts of all beings, O Arjuna, causing all beings, by His illusive power, to revolve as if mounted on a machine.

Comment: 'It was all part of a play' - Draupadi-vastra-harana was also Krishna's play?! Is there any question on Mahabharata that can't be answered using this reasoning?

Comment: @sv. There were never two separate entities Krishna and Draupadi.

Comment: So the answer to why Krishna didn't stop Duhshasana from disrobing Draupadi is: Krishna caused Duhshasana/himself (BG 18.61) to disrobe Draupadi/himself (BG 18.61). So he caused himself to disrobe himself! No crime committed. Excellent!

Comment: Exactly. It's like when you get hurt in a dream. The one who hurts, and one who gets hurts, both are same.

Comment: So the whole Mahabharata is a dream of Krishna. In the dream, Krishna is playing every character himself. This is even better!